# How to block/unblock copy/paste on ubuntu (or other)?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, clipboard

When using a windows application with wine on ubuntu, I noticed that when running, it disables all copy/paste on my system (menus, ctrl-c ctrl-v shourtcuts...)

What I understood, is that this was performed in a platform-independant way (since the software was written for windows *specifically using VisualBasic 6.0*)

My question is: How to perform this block/unblock?

I don't need a programming language specific (that would be helpful), I just want to understand the generic solution that I will implement with any programming language.

Thanks

Comment: You could continuously set the clipboard to an empty string. I

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is some block/unblock. It's just the fact that there are some [minor problems with copy/paste implementation on Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/CopyAndPaste).

Comment: I don't have any problems, I want to understand how it works and how to reproduce the feature (regardless of using or not wine)

Comment: @skafandri But there is no such general standard feature to block/unblock all keyboard

Comment: Is not about the keyboard, copy/paste with any mean, like menu